# Excel Data Manipulation

Tags: c#, excel, checkbox, radio-button, cell

I am able to open up a pre-set excel document (.xls/.xlsx) and change particular cells using:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range date = theWorkSheet1.UsedRange;
date = date.get_Range("B4");
date.Value = theDate;
```

However, this only allows me to change the specified cell values (in this case **B4**). I have come across **`Radio Buttons`** and **`Check Boxes`** and would like to change those values in the current excel sheet using my GUI with custom functionality. So if something in my C# GUI is checked or enabled, the radio buttons/check boxes in the excel file will change accordingly.

There are more than one set of radio buttons and check boxes.

Can anyone help me figure out how to read the different groups of radio buttons and check boxes and properly populate them according to a set of rules?

Comment: When I did some Office interop stuff a few years back, I found it poorly documented and hard to get answers.  If you can rely on having xlsx documents as the source (rather than older xls), you may want to look at Microsoft's Open XML SDK http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: @Eric J: unfortunately most/all of the documents will be the older format (xls)... I just added the xlsx in case the documents ever get updated.... which they probably will not :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Worksheet object will have properties on it called `CheckBoxes` and `OptionButtons`. Each of these is a collection of all the checkboxes and option buttons on the worksheet, respectively. You can set their `Value` property to 0 (unchecked), 1 (checked) or 2 (indeterminate), for example:

> *worksheet*.Checkboxes("Checkbox1").Value = 1

Some worksheets may have OLEObjects on them instead of plain old Excel Checkboxes, in which case you'll have to do this:

> *worksheet*.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Value = 1

Comment: That is great! One problem though.. I cannot seem to find/use the `CheckBoxes` and `OptionButtons` properties. I tried `theWorkSheet1.CheckBoxes` and `theWorkSheet1.OptionsButtons` but neither worked... do you know why that could be?

Comment: For Each a in ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes : MsgBox a.Name : Next

Comment: So the problem is.. I am using a C# program that opens up an excel workbook... and from the C# program.. depending on if certain rules occur will change the actual excel spreadsheet's checkboxes that are checked and/or the choice for the optionsbuttons...

Comment: what i'm saying is, create a VBA macro on the worksheet that you think has checkboxes on it (as an experiment) and run that code ^ This will help you determine if there are actually checkboxes on the sheet and what they are named. If they are there you should be able to set theWorkSheet1.CheckBoxes(*name*).Value from C#.

Comment: I am not too familiar with VBA macros in excel.. but I think I figured it out... however no message box appeared... I can see the checkboxes and the optionsbuttons on the sheet.. I am curious on why they are not **actually** there...? Is there a way to check to see if the options buttons are there? If both are not there.... what is going on?

Comment: Maybe it's an OLEObject? Try For Each a in ActiveSheet.OLEObjects : MsgBox x.Name : Next

Comment: Yes they are OLEObjects! the message box(es) popped up! Is there a way to go about this with my question above?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to walk me through what was going on! I greatly appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Assign value to checkbox in Excel file using C#  by PradeepLutare

// Get the Excel file location

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\LPL\LPLRating.xls", misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

// Pass the Workbook Name from that excel file

workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item("Rate Sheet - Primary");

// assigne value according to your logic.

workSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = true;